# Find the general expression for the values of a steady state vector of an $n\times n$ transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

I have a question that is asking to find the values of the elements in the steady state vector for a regular transition matrix **P** of size $n \times n$. All I'm given is that the the elements in each row of the transition matrix sum to 1.

So I guess I'm supposed to find a generic formula for the value of each element in the steady state vector but I have no idea how to even start.

do I need to use the $\left(I-P\right)\mathbf{q}=0$ formula?

I feel like I understand how to find the steady state vector for a given transition matrix, but without knowing anything but the dimensions of P I'm stuck. Any hints would be much appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: perhaps I should clarify, the columns of the matrix are the probability vectors, so they add to 1 by definition, however that the rows sum to one is not by definition the case (just the case in this example). Also, unless the textbook I'm reading from is entirely wrong it definitely is $\left( I-P \right)q=0$, its in front of me on the page as we speak. but thankyou anyway, I will look at that wikipedia page

Comment: hmm, interesting, in Anton and Rorres, elementary linear algebra 11th edition

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: My impression was that both conventions are in widespread use, possibly in different fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all rows sum to $1$, the vector

$$
\frac1n\pmatrix{1\\\vdots\\1}
$$

(with $n$ $1$s) is an eigenvector of the transition matrix with eigenvalue $1$. Since the chain is regular, it has a unique stationary distribution, so this is *the* stationary distribution.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, I'm really confused though because we haven't covered anything on eigenvectors yet in the course so I'm assuming there must be a way to do it without using them?

Comment: @Lincoln77: That's just another expression for what you wrote. An eigenvector of a matrix $P$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ is a vector $q$ satisfying $Pq=\lambda q$. For $\lambda=1$, this is $Pq=q$, or $(I-P)q=0$, as you wrote.

Comment: hmm, ok. But if we're looking for a vector such that Pq=q, wouldn't we just take the column of 1's? since then we have a linear combination of the columns of P, and since we know each row sums to 1 we end up with just a column of 1's again? in other words why do we need the 1/n term?

Comment: @Lincoln77: I thought that by "steady state vector" you were referring to a stationary distribution of a Markov process. A probability distribution is normalised to $1$. If you just want any vector that's invariant when you apply the matrix, you don't need the normalisation.

Comment: no im pretty sure you are right, but I just dont understand the 1/n term, like, how doees it get there, what does it do? this is for a question on an assignment but we've barely even covered determinants, havent done anything all on like null space or eigen anything, now suddenly were supposed to show how to get the values for this steady state vector... its stressful.

Comment: @Lincoln77: You're looking for a probability distribution. Probability distributions are normalised to $1$, i.e. the sum of all probabilties is $1$ (since the probability that the process is in some state is $1$). If you have any vector $q$ satisfying $(I-P)q=0$, then any multiple of $q$ also satisfies that equation. So given the vector of $1$s, you can divide it by the sum of its entries in order to normalise the sum of the entries to $1$. The sum of $n$ $1$s is $n$.

Comment: ahh, thanks @joriki ! i get it! so its because q is also a probability vector, thats what i missed. Thank you for your really helpful answers :)

Answer (score 0):

The term "steady state vector" usually refers to a stationary distribution for $P$; that is, a *row* vector $\pi$ with entries that add to $1$, such that $\pi P=\pi$. Because $P$ is regular, $\lim_nP^n =\Pi$. ($\Pi$ is the  $n\times n$ matrix whose every row is $\pi$.) Consequently, if $q$ is any column vector then $\lim_nP^nq$ is a column vector whose every entry is equal to $\sum_k\pi_kq_k$.